# Console-App to get all open files for processes

Tags: windows, process, console, filenames

I am searching for a console-app (where I can pipe the output to a txt-file) which gives me a list of all current processes and the files which each process has open. The tool should also work when the user doesn't has administrativ-privilegues and it should also give file-path which are located on the network (UNC and absolute/mappings).

Is there something like this which I can call from another tool and get the information?

I am on a windows system. **I have a open filename and need now to get the whole path for the file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a unix-like system, `lsof` lists open files.

Comment: Handle needs administrative privilege.

Comment: It would be a security hole to let any user spy on what files other users have open.

Comment: I need only "my" files - that means the files of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're on the Unix systems that don't ship with `lsof`, `fuser` is the usual replacement tool.